# Mock MongoDB's @realm/react for testing authentication states with jest

Tags: mongodb, react-native, jestjs, realm

I have written an app in `React-Native` and implemented a cloud-sync mechanism using MongoDB's `Realm` and `@realm/react` packages. All works great, but now I want to implement tests with jest to ensure my app's ui respond correctly to changes in the state of the user, especially: Does my UI hierarchy (and the components in it) correctly update when a user signs on/off.

To do so, I'm looking for a way to mock the user object in the `@realm/react` package. I'm trying to stick as closely to the implementation that users will actually use, so I'm not looking to simply mock some user object to be returned from the `useUser` hook. I want to actually mock a user into the `AppProvider` context, so that the `UserProvider` receives it, and displays either the user-aware stack or the fallback view.

I've been poking around both the `@realm-react` and `Realm-js` packages in my node-modules for the past couple of days, and despite seeing al the functions to authenticate there, I haven't been able to localize the actual implementations to see what's inside of them and correctly mock them.

**Question**
How does one mock either `@realm/react` or `realm-js` to manipulate the user object (either a fake one or none at all) being present in realms AppProvider context, allowing one to test the way their app responds to different authentication states?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.